# Destructive Changes throwing warning ApexClass not found

Tags: apex, destructivechanges.xml

I'm trying to deploy `destructiveChanges` to my org. The error I keep receiving is `Warning: No ApexClass named: CLASS_NAME` not found. I find this bizarre because this class **DOES** exist in the org.

Why is this happening?

```
<types>
  <members>CLASS_NAME</members>
  <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<version>45.0</version>
```

Comment: How does your destructive xml look like? Which tool are you using for the deploying ?

Comment: We have a custom job that is connected to our repos where we run the code from.

Comment: What api or tool that does job use ?

Comment: your destructivechanges xml seems incomplete. I'd expect a <name> tag as well inside the <types>

Comment: forgot to add it in post, just added it

Comment: Okay, possibly silly question: are you sure it matches case-sensitive to the class name?

Comment: Hey @user2582622 did you ever solve this? Having the same problem today with a destructiveChanges.xml saying a class doesn't exist even though it 100% does exist and is a letter for letter match to whats listed in the xml